# Object doesn't support this property or method - jquery simple modal popup

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

My code runs as follows,

```
    <script src="../../Content/js/jquery.simplemodal.js" type="text/javascript">      </script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/basic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../Content/css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/css/basic_ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function Add(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Details",
        data: { Id: id },
        success: function (result) {
            $.modal(result);

        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(error + req + status);
        }
    });
}
```

The button click triggers this Add javascript method, But doesnt open the page in the modal pop up. Help in solving this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that `result` returns valid html? Also check to make sure that $.modal is not null or undefined

Comment: @ashiq AN: Please share the code at the server side.

Comment: Also, I just noticed you are adding jquery.js twice: `<script src="../../Content/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and '<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'. It shouldn't be the reason your code is failing, but it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @dhinesh: This is the action in the server side                public ActionResult Details()
        {
            //Code goes here
            return PartialView("Details");
        }

Comment: @Andrey: Yes it returns a valid Html. I tested using a alert.

Comment: @ashiq: check to make sure $.modal is defined as well

Comment: @Andrey: Yes $.modal is undefined. How can i solve this?

Comment: hm, try to load jquery first, as @njbooher suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery.simplemodal.js needs to be loaded after jQuery.js

Comment: @njbooher: can you edit your answer, so I could remove my down vote, which I casted by mistake. it doesn't let me remove the vote unless you make any changes to the answer